# How to remove ' ' quotation marks and square brackets [] from strings when adding to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I have the following lists:

```
list = []
a = 'a'
b = 'b'
c = 2
d = 3
list.append(a)
list.append(b)
list.append(c)
list.append(d)
```

And I'm adding `list` to a new txt file, which I want to show like that:

```
a,b,2,3
```

However, instead I'm getting:

```
['a','b',2,3]
```

How do I remove the [] and ''s?

Comment: Please update your question with the code which is writing to a new txt file.

Comment: btw Don't use `list` as a variable name. It is a built-in.

Answer (score 1):

Join the list with ',' separator. And then write to file.

```py
res = ",".join(str(x) for x in list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something to try instead

```
sub output()
Dim a as string, b as string
Dim c as integer, d as integer
a = "a"
b = "b"
c = 2
d = 3
list = a & "," & b & "," & c & "," & d
end sub
```

this should concatenate the string data to be the value of each variable with commas between. I think the output you are getting is the reference, not the string value.
so you just make the location you want the data to show up = to list.

Comment: err... Which language are you using?